# Inverting columns and rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    PA.PK, PA.PACKAGE_NAME, ATTR.ENGLISH_NAME ATTRIBUTES, 
    PA.VALUE, ATTR_LIST.ENGLISH_NAME ATTRIBUTES_LIST
FROM 
    POSTS_ATTRIBUTES PA 
INNER JOIN 
    POSTS P ON PA.POSTS = P.PK
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ATTRIBUTES ATTR ON PA.ATTRIBUTES = ATTR.PK
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ATTRIBUTES_LIST ATTR_LIST ON PA.ATTRIBUTES_LIST = ATTR_LIST.PK
WHERE 
    P.FIELDS  = 83;
```

Which gives output like this

```
PK | PACKAGE_NAME | ATTRIBUTES            | VALUE  | ATTRIBUTES_LIST 
------------------------------------------------------------------
211| CERAMICS     | RAW MATERIALS         | (null) | CEMENT 
212| CERAMICS     | PRODUCTION OPERATIONS | (null) | PRESSING 
213| CERAMICS     | OPERATIONAL SERVICES  | (null) | FORK LIFTS RENTAL 
214| CERAMICS     | FINISHED PRODUCTS     | (null) | FLOOR CERAMICS
```

Is there any way to invert columns and rows via a query to make it looks like

```
PACKAGE_NAME | RAW MATERIALS | PRODUCTION OPERATIONS | OPERATIONAL SERVICES | FINISHED PRODUCTS 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CERAMICS     |    CEMENT     |      PRESSING         |   FORK LIFTS RENTAL  |  FLOOR CERAMICS
```

Comment: Google "Pivoting" - that's what this operation is called. There's plenty of articles on how to do in Oracle. Documentation is here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Comment: Appreciated :) @Jasmine